# Java 9 The type URL is not visible

Tags: eclipse, java-9

Eclipse oxygen; windows 7; JDK 9 final from 9, 21.
Just trying to port an old application written for Java 6 but also compiled with java 8. On the line:

```
String path = Config.class.getResource("").getPath();
```

With JDK 9 I get the error: "The type URL is not visible".

Further, the line:

```
URL url = Config.class.getResource(Config.get(iconPath));
```

tells me: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from URL to URL"

I can't find any hint in the API description for Java 9, nor in the migration guide telling me, that either of it is related to restrictions of internal API access.
Beside The erros poped up a little later. Before, I could compile and run the application!
May be a proplem of eclipse java 9 beta plugin.
Do anybody know more about it?

Comment: Do you have the fully qualified name of Config? Also what is printing the "The type URL is not visible" message, is this Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the _[Java 9 Support for Oxygen](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-oxygen)_ plug-in?

Comment: *cannot convert from URL to URL* you must add the code with the fully qualified name of your classes in use or share the imports used as Alan said.

Comment: @Bateman: It's eclipse

Comment: @howgler: latest version. The imports are shared, projects and pathes are known. As I said, on using jdk 8, which is still default for the workspace, there is no problem. I have also an ant script, to compile without eclipse. But for now I'm actually searching to convince ant to use Java 8 or 9 and not 6! :))

Comment: All that can be said without knowing a reproducible problem and the way to reproduce it, is that this might be platform specific.

Comment: on using ant and jdk9, the project can be compiled. Hence, I guess it's eclipse and the java9 support plugin

Comment: I assume Config is one of your classes and it's not in a named module. In that case, Config.class.getResource will behaves the same as JDK 8 and older releases. So there is something else going on here and the errors you see must be coming from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

@ Alan: Your assumption is right. As I said it’s an old application built for Java 6. Just for fun I was curious to see what happened with Java 9. Running the jar compiled with Java 6 using java 9, no problem it works. Hence next step was to try to compile the source with Java9 and to run it with Java9, not changing any code or declaration. Then the mentioned error popped up. With Java 8 and before, java.net.URL was not imported, as it was an intermediate! 
Eclipse with Java 9 don’t like it and mention the error "The type URL is not visible" and don’t compile. When I import java.net.URL, it works and the application can be compiled and run. However now Eclipse suggest to “remove the unused import”!
I guess, this requires a little fix of the Eclipse Java 9 plugin!